# is there any way we can sort only blanks go last remaining not sort at all in java?

Tags: java, comparator

is there any way we can make blank values go last and which are not blank not sort at all.
I have requirement like

```
    userroles-admin,developer,blank field
```

I have to sort blanks go last and if incase of admin,developer (which is not blank) they should not sort and it should consider nearest future date to process.

logic i have used:

```
userList
  .stream()
  .sorted(
     Comparator
       .Comparing(User::getUserRole, roleComparator)
       .thenComparing(user::getJoinedDate, DateComparator))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

so below is the custom comparator for only blanks but its sorting even admin and developer also.

```
    public class roleComparator implements Comparator<String> {
         @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                if (o1.equals(o2)) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (o1.isBlank()) { 
             
                    return 1;
                }
                return -1;
            }
    
   }
```

when i tried to sort this it is not giving proper order, it should give first not blank values for role and date follows which is nearest future date and as per output here it is taking blank values in last but its taking sorted order as admin first and developer second which should not and giving wrong results. for example:

```
    1.user("admin","04/30/2022")
    2.user("developer","04/28/2022")
    3.user("developer","04/31/2022")`
    4.user("","04/27/2022")
```

order should be: 2134 but its taking 2314

Comment: Please any one help on this?

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to FILTER OUT all blank lines, and just sort the non-empty ones? So that you ONLY get lines with content? Whats the point of moving around empty lines?

Comment: @GhostCat The OP wants non-blank lines to come out in their original order, NOT sorted.

Comment: @Mounika I cleaned up the formatting in your post.  Please use the `Edit` link to examine the changes I made, to learn how to format future posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is in your first line, you are comparing strings using String.equals, but that's not what you want. You want all "non-blank" Strings to be equal

```
public int compare(String a, String b) 
  if (a.isBlank()) return 1;
  if (b.isBlank()) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that this depends on the fact that `Stream.sorted()` is guaranteed to be ***stable***, which means it preserves original order for equal items.  This is NOT always guaranteed in the general case of a sort operation.

Comment: @JimGarrison Good comment. But that the sort algorithm needs to be able to do this is a pre-condition to solving this problem by implementing the right comparator

Comment: Yes, I was just pointing out that sort stability is not guaranteed _in general_, but is part of the contract for `Stream.sorted()` in this case.

Comment: This will probably work here, but according to the specification, a Comparator should satisfy `sgn(compare(a, b)) == -sgn(compare(b, a))` which is violated if both `a` and `b` are blank. A fully correct implementation should also return zero if both `a` and `b` are blank. Some algorithms may not terminate with this comparator.

Comment: Both the approaches are working as expected. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I used lambda's to construct the `Comparators`. I believe, based on the comments, this is what you wanted.

```
Comparator<String> roleComparator = (o1,o2)->
          o1.isBlank() && o2.isBlank() ? 0 :
              o1.isBlank() ? 1 : o2.isBlank() ? -1 : 0;

Comparator<User> comp = Comparator.comparing(User::getRole, 
      roleComparator).thenComparing(
                User::getJoinedDate, dateComparator);
```

You can specify `comp` as the `sort comparator`.

I tested this using a `selection sort`, which is known to be unstable, by shuffling a list using both a stable `(Collections.sort)` and the selection sort and comparing the results.  But still, an unstable sort will not always exhibit instability.

Comment: how to get the highest priority from the same below example?
for example:
 1.user("100","admin","04/30/2022")
    2.user("0","developer","04/28/2022")
    3.user("1","developer","04/31/2022")`
    4.user("100","developer","04/27/2022")

i want to have max priority users in list(1,4) in single array list. Please help